# SQL Server Where Clause Performance

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a SQL query which looks over 10 conditions in where clause. I am not sure which way of below would be better in terms of performance. Some of my parameters are important and some are secondary.

If you can explain which is better and why I would be grateful.

**My Params**

```
DECLARE @ParamImportant1 int, @ParamImportant2 int, @ParamImportant2 int,
@ParamSecondary1 int, @ParamSecondary2 int,@ParamSecondary3 int
```

**First Method**
I have an index which contains all params.

```
SELECT 
* 
FROM MyTable
WHERE Col1 = @ParamImportant1 AND Col2 = @ParamImportant2 AND Col3 = @ParamImportant3
AND (@ParamSecondary1 IS NULL OR ColSec1 = @ParamSecondary1)
AND (@ParamSecondary2 IS NULL OR ColSec2 = @ParamSecondary2)
AND (@ParamSecondary3 IS NULL OR ColSec3 = @ParamSecondary3)
```

**Second Method**
Dividing query using subquery or cte.

```
SELECT
*
FROM
(
   SELECT 
   * 
   FROM MyTable
   WHERE Col1 = @ParamImportant1 AND Col2 = @ParamImportant2 AND Col3 = @ParamImportant3
) X
WHERE (@ParamSecondary1 IS NULL OR ColSec1 = @ParamSecondary1)
AND (@ParamSecondary2 IS NULL OR ColSec2 = @ParamSecondary2)
AND (@ParamSecondary3 IS NULL OR ColSec3 = @ParamSecondary3)
```

**Third Method**
Using Temp Table

```
 SELECT 
 * 
 INTO #MyTemp
 FROM MyTable
 WHERE Col1 = @ParamImportant1 AND Col2 = @ParamImportant2 AND Col3 = @ParamImportant3

SELECT
*
FROM #MyTemp
WHERE (@ParamSecondary1 IS NULL OR ColSec1 = @ParamSecondary1)
AND (@ParamSecondary2 IS NULL OR ColSec2 = @ParamSecondary2)
AND (@ParamSecondary3 IS NULL OR ColSec3 = @ParamSecondary3)
```

Comment: Do you really intend to use `SELECT *` here?  By selecting columns other than `Col1`, `Col2`, and `Col3`, SQL Server might choose to not even use the index you defined.

Comment: Have you used the SQL explain method to show what it does? or the profiler?

Comment: It depends on the structure of your data, there's no definitivne answer. In genereal: check the stats and explain plan for each case on your data (I always start with number of reads)

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen No! Just for example. I will select just required columns.

Comment: This looks like a catch-all query as well. I'd suggest using `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` as otherwise (if this is a stored procedure) the cached query plan is very unlikely to be useful to every call to the SP.

Comment: @BugFinder. Yes. However, my query is very complex. I just need some suggestion. Dividing `WHERE` clause is good or bad?

Comment: @Larnu I think your answer has no relation with my question.

Comment: I'd suggest it is, @MehmetOtkun. Have a read of Gail's articles on ([Revisiting](https://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2018/03/13/revisiting-catch-all-queries/)) [Catch-all Queries](https://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/03/19/catch-all-queries/). You'll notice the exact type of queries she's discussing here are the style you have.

Comment: @MehmetOtkun as a whole splitting it up is likely to make more work so arguably should be slower.

Comment: This arguably belongs on dba.stackexchange.com.  You may get more answers there.

Answer (score 0):

Under most circumstances, your first version should work well:

```
WHERE Col1 = @ParamImportant1 AND
      Col2 = @ParamImportant2 AND
      Col3 = @ParamImportant3 AND
      (@ParamSecondary1 IS NULL OR ColSec1 = @ParamSecondary1) AND
     (@ParamSecondary2 IS NULL OR ColSec2 = @ParamSecondary2) AND
     (@ParamSecondary3 IS NULL OR ColSec3 = @ParamSecondary3)
```

The index that you want needs to start with the three important columns.  It can then include the other columns as well `(col1, col2, col3, colsec1, colsec2, colsec3)`.

Note that the index will be scanned through all values of `col1, col2, col3`.  That is, the index will not reduce the number of rows for the secondary columns.

Under most circumstances, that seems reasonable.  If this is not, then you may need multiple indexes and dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid "smart logic" in your parameters, otherwise MSSQL cannot figure out the best way of getting the data.

> The most reliable method for arriving at the best execution plan is to avoid unnecessary filters in the SQL statement.

https://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/where-clause/obfuscation/smart-logic